# Prevent change of 'copied' object affecting original using ng-repeat in angular

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a setup in angular which displays a json string called 'items'. Each item contains an array of field ids. By matching the field ids, it pulls information for the fields using a seperate 'fields' json string.

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Item 1",
      "fields": [
        1,
        1
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Item 2",
      "fields": [
        1,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "fsdfs"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can copy or delete either the items or fields, which will modify the 'items' json.

Everything works except when I copy one item (and its fields), and then choose to delete a field for that specific item.

What happens is that it deletes the field for both the copied item AND the original.

Plunker -

http://plnkr.co/edit/hN8tQiBMBhQ1jwmPiZp3?p=preview

I've read that using 'track by' helps to index each item as unique and prevent duplicate keys, but this seems to be having no effect.

Any help appreciated, thanks

**Edit -**

Credit to Eric McCormick for this one, using angular.copy with array.push solved this issue.

Instead of -

```
$scope.copyItem = function (index) {
       items.data.push({
            id: $scope.items.data.length + 1,
            title: items.data[index].title,
            fields: items.data[index].fields
        });
}
```

This worked -

```
$scope.copyItem = function (index) {
 items.data.push(angular.copy(items.data[index])); 
 }
```

Comment: As nice as the plunker is, it would really help to include your code here (at least the relevant parts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using [*angular.copy*](//docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy), which is a "deep copy" of the source object. This is a unique object from the source one.

It may seem slightly counter-intuitive, but a direct reference (as you're observing) interacts with the original object. If you [inspect the element's scope](//stackoverflow.com/a/13744085/1720082) after it's instantiated in the DOM, you can see there's a *$id* property assigned to the object in memory. Basically, by using *angular.copy(source, destination)*, you ensure a copying of all the properties/values and having a unique object.

Example:

```
//inside the controller, a function to instantiate new copy of selected object
this.selectItem = function(item){
  var copyOfItem = angular.copy(item);
  //new item with same properties and values but unique object!
}
```

Egghead.io has [a video on angular.copy](//egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-copy-for-deep-copy).